# Cannot get $state.go to work from within directive, but have access to $state properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, state, directive

I have a directive that is attribute based which holds my login component. Everything is working correctly. The JWT is returned, the HTTP request works just fine...but I can access $state.current.name just fine, but `$state.go` does absolutely nothing. I have also tried to use `$state.transitionTo` with no success.

I use this exact same `$state.go` call all over the place. What's the deal here?

```
app.directive('login', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope, authentication, $state, jwt, $cookies) {
      $scope.user = {};
      $scope.login = function() {
        authentication.login($scope.user)
          .success(function(response, status, headers) {
            var headersObject = headers();
            jwt.set(headersObject.token);
            $scope.errors = null;
            $scope.hasErrors = false;
            $state.go('someState');
            console.log($state.current.name);
          })
          .error(function(response) {
            $scope.errors = response.data;
            $scope.hasErrors = true;
          });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Sorry, deleted the answer as it was incorrect.

Comment: show your routes. can you provide a fiddle to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: add a plunker reproducing your problem